# Why does the T-1000 in the Galleria Mall look at the bronze statue like that?

Tags: terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

In the fight scene with the T-800 at the Galleria Mall, there is a scene  where the T-1000 looks at a bronze-like statue. What does the slight grin on the T-1000's face mean? Machines don't have feelings, so this seems a bit strange to me.

Both samples points to the same scene.

Comment: I interpret the T-1000's expression as confusion, as though he's thinking "WTF???" It could just be a moment of humor. However, I've seen the movie a dozen times and that moment is confusing to me, too.

Comment: I never thought it meant anything. I thought the T-1000 just noticed something that looked like him in this liquid metal form

Comment: D....daddy? Probably not that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simply a scene of [irony](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Irony).

The liquid terminator sees an effigy of itself made by human (the mannequin), while its there with the mission to kill all humans. (Ofc indirectly via time travel magics) This is meant for the viewer, not the terminator.

There is certainly no smirk in that photo. Though maybe there is an internal one.

[image: photo]

Answer (score 4):

#### Possible explanations:

1. T-1000 was looking at it in order to check if it was another T-1000 which could help in catching John Connor.
2. T-1000 was scanning it so it could transform into the bronze statue in the future if it needed it.

Comment: I love that first suggestion! The second one wouldn't fit into the director's cut of the movie, which shows that the T-1000 has to touch something physically in order to sample or mimic it. Just seeing it isn't enough. (That isn't a requirement in the theatrical release, though.)

Comment: @BrettFromLA Well, T-1000 could touch it while looking at it, because we can't see its hand in this scene )

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in [the script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator-2-Judgement-Day.html) to show why the T-1000 glanced at the at the mannequin.

> THIRD LEVEL CONCOURSE:
> A plate glass window EXPLODES and Terminator crashes through to the tile floor like a sack of cement amid the screaming crowd.
>
> **T-1000 turns without a word** and heads back through the store after John, accelerating slowly into a loping, predatory run.

In the [official novelisation](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_(novel)), based on an earlier version of the script, 'Officer Austen' got himself entangled with one of the store's mannequins and "*swatted it aside*". This scene may be a reference to that.

> When he glanced up again, a man crashed through the third floor
> metal-and-glass railing and arced out in an ungraceful back-flip, as
> if he had been flung like a ragdoll. He hit like a sack of wet cement
> amid the screaming crowd.
>
> **Officer Austin appeared at the railing, swatting aside a store
> mannequin that had gotten entangled around his leg,** and glanced down.
> The security guard lowered the gun, uncertain, as he saw the cop
> abruptly turn and walk out of sight.

Out-of-universe it's a bit of foreshadowing (for first-time viewers) and a nice reward for audiences who're watching the film a second time.

> **James Cameron:** *I love that moment* [when the T-1000 looks at the mannqeuin] *but it only works if you've already seen the film already* [laughs].
>
> <sub><sup>[T2: Director's Audio Commentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?si=WJx4r-tY2haTerFn&t=1965&v=XpRMwfUt6gc&feature=youtu.be)</sup></sub>

Answer (score -2):

Curiosity. Unlike most Terminators T1000 has ability to convey emotional outputs far greater than T800 series.

It smiles, converses, lies, displays humor. Even torments targets.

The T1000 doesn't have conventional sensors so data acquisition is based on contact assessment. The mannequin caught it off guard until he realized it's simply nothing and not a threat.